# Swift - Rotating Multiple Views through UIRotationGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, uikit, swift5

I am attempting to make it so that when you rotate one view through `UIRotationGestureRecognizer` then all the views that I need to rotate will also rotate.

The issue appears to be with setting my `gesture.rotation = 0`, the current method allows only for the first item in the array to be able to rotated but the rest do not.

The Apple docs suggest to cache the rotation and use it from there, however I cannot properly do so without weird bugs appearing.

Does anyone know how I can go about fixing this so that all my views that I need rotated will rotate upon one view being rotated? Perhaps through properly caching the rotation?

```
@objc func didRotate(_ sender: UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {
        
        let rotation = sender.rotation
        
        self.transform = self.transform.rotated(by: rotation)
        
        for viewToRotate in rotatingViews {
            viewToRotate.didRotate(sender)
        }
        
        sender.rotation = 0.0
    }
```

Comment: Your code makes no sense. I cannot imagine how it could possibly compile. What does `viewToRotate(sender)` supposedly do?

Comment: Thanks for the catch, updated the code, and it compiles just fine

Comment: OK, well, the problem is you're reusing the gesture recognizer in a funny way. Don't call `didRotate` in some sort of loop, just let the rotation gesture call it and rotate all the views directly as needed.